# When setting up bitcoin node on raspberry pi get as far as ./configure code stops at checking whether the C++ compiler works get ...no

Tags: c++, git, git-clone

Trying to configure new bitcoin node on raspberry pi after giving ./configure command it goes as far as checking for g++...g++
and the following is returned

checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/pi/bitcoin':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executable

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you install a C++ compiler?

Comment: Mining bitcoin on a *raspberry pi*? But why? That's just burning electricity for no gain. Those systems are great for many things, but mining is *not* one of them. Seems like a waste of both time and energy to me.

Comment: @JesperJuhl hopefully op will realize that once they make 0.00001 bitcoin per week

Comment: @JesperJuhl They did not say anything about mining. The Pi is more than capable of running a full Bitcoin node.